# Monte Carlo Integration approach with Mathematica

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I have been working on Monte Carlo Integration approach with Mathematica problem.
Here is the description: Approximate the values of the following integrals using the Monte Carlo Integration approach. In each case, use a sufficiently large number of samples so that you have a reasonably accurate approximation to the exact value. Please show the details of your computational setup and the resulting numerical estimate
[![Equation I am working on][1]][1]

Here is my Mathematica Code

```
Remove["Global`*"]
U:Random[]
f[x_,y_,z_]=z^3(x-y)^2
X:=6.0(*(3-0)*(2-0)*(1-0)*) (*I am not sure this part*)
avg = Sum[f[X],{1000000}]/1000000
mc = 6.0 * avg(*I am not sure this part*)
```

Could you help with correcting code especially the two line I put (*I am not sure this part*)
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/qQWkp.png

Comment: I tried `Remove["Global\`*"]; f[x_,y_,z_]:=z^3(x-y)^2; Print[Integrate[f[x,y,z],{x,0,3},{y,0,2},{z,0,1}]]; avg=Sum[f[3*RandomReal[],2*RandomReal[],RandomReal[]],{10^6}]/10^6` which returned 2 and 0.333239 This needs to be changed. I used RandomReal because my Mathematica is newer. Please edit your post to explain what I have not understood. If as an experiment I do `Remove["Global\`*"]; f[x_,y_]:=If[x^2+y^2<=1,1,0]; avg=N[Sum[f[RandomReal[], RandomReal[]],{10^6}]/10^6]` then it returns 0.78754 which is approximately pi/4.